# Excel How to Highlight cells in a row for equal Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm curious to know if there is a way to apply conditional formatting to cells within a row for cells that are equal.

For example I have dates in several columns.  For rows that contain dates that are equal to other date columns I wish to highlight these cells to make them pop out.

**Example of data:**
[image]

**Example of individual cells conditional formatting:**
[image]

Comment: Try to use Conditional Formatting.

Comment: @Lee Well certainly.  Which is why I originally tagged the question with the tag `conditional-formatting`.  How to utilize this feature or any other feature to reach my intended goal is the question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Sample Data rang is `A1:G9`.
- Hold **Ctrl button** Select Cells, 
  you want to Highlight for
  duplicate Dates, by **Mouse Click**.
- From `HOME TAB` select **Condition 
  Formatting**, **Highlight Cells Rule** then 
  **Duplicate Values.**

[image]

- From next dialogue box, assure `DUPLICATE` 
  option has been selected.
- From list on Right select color combination or 
  you may hit `Custom Format`.

[image]

- Apply an appropriate color and finish with 
  **Ok**.

Comment: It 'almost' works.  Not sure if I am just missing a step but it is also highlighting duplicates within the Column.  If there are dups within a column I don't care... I only am looking to highlight dups in rows.  What am I missing?  in the example screenshot you provided there are no duplicates dates in your columns and so it's hard to tell if you solution would work based on the sample data you used.  Again, I only say this as I am unable to get the duplicate feature NOT to find dups in the column.

Comment: @CodeNovice, nothing wrong with the procedure,, just for neatness I've not included many Duplicate Dates,, otherwise it works for Column also. For example  enter `01/01/19` in Column C in any Cell, will be highlighted,, since Column has `01/01/19` already in first Cell. Since you found solution is working then you may accept it as answer as well as up vote also. ☺